# Grep and regex, Why does the following return only a specific portion?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Why in the following:

```
echo this is a line. | grep -o -E "[a-z]+\."
```

The result is `line.` and not `this is a line.`?

There is no word boundary or any other restriction on the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[a-z]` only matches the characters `a` to `z`. they do not match the space character. when you want to match also the space character you have to explicitly say so: `[a-z ]`.

Comment: `[a-z] only matches the characters a to z`. Yes I understand.But why in this case it is `line` that matches and not `this` or `is` or `this is a line`?

Comment: because your pattern has a dot in the end. `line.` is the only part that matches "at least one of `a` to `z` followed by a dot".

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` option instructs grep to limit the output to just that part of the line which matches the pattern.

Rerun the command without `-o` and the result will indeed be

`this is a line.`